# Cannot iterate multiple JSON value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use JSON value to view data in ng-repeat. But I am getting only first value. I tried using other method but not getting the value properly.

**My JSON response:-**

```
{
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [
      {
        "attribute": {
          "_name": "text-align",
          "__prefix": "xsl",
          "__text": "center"
        },
        "_name": "__frontmatter",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "space-before",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "80mm"
          },
          {
            "_name": "space-before.conditionality",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "retain"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-size",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "22pt"
          },
          {
            "_name": "font-weight",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "bold"
          },
          {
            "_name": "line-height",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "140%"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      }
    ],
    "_xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
    "_xmlns:fo": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
}
```

On suggestion from previous question I want to achieve all the datas from `"__name"` from the `"attribute"` key.

I tried this as suggested on my **controller:-**

```
console.log($scope.jsonObj);
                angular.forEach($scope.jsonObj,function(value,key){
                 console.log(value["attribute-set"][0]["attribute"]["_name"]);
                    });
```

**jsonObj** is my JSON object

The output is `text-align` in my console which is the 1st `_name` attribute value .

How can I achieve ng-repeat of `_name` value from this JSON ?

Comment: `attribute` is an object first, then an array, is that correct? if so you need to check what it is and if array, then you'll have to iterate through again

Comment: Why don't you create a new scope var: $scope.records = jsonObj.stylesheet.attribute-set;  and then you can iterate this records: ng-repeat="record in records"

Comment: @DarrenSweeney its correct , I am converting this from xsl file.

Comment: @Curlas It's showing `set is not defined` when using `$scope.records = $scope.jsonObj.stylesheet.attribute-set;`

Comment: i'm sorry, the javascript parser it's reading "attribute-set" like a math operator. Try:
$scope.records = $scope.jsonObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"]

Comment: @Curlas I did this in my view `<div ng-repeat="record in records">{{record.attribute-set}}</div>` and it's showing NaN in my view as only `attribute-set` objects are repeating. I want to show `_name` under `attribute` to get repeated in my view

Comment: each "record" in view must be one object like this 
{
        "attribute": {
          "_name": "text-align",
          "__prefix": "xsl",
          "__text": "center"
        },
        "_name": "__frontmatter",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      } You could use <div ng-repeat="record in records">{{record.attribute.__name}}</div> but now, I've seen the JSON seems to be wrong??it's and object whith one attribute "styleshhet". This one is an object with a attribute ""attribute-set"", and this is an array of objects, but the sencond object has an attributte witch is an array... mmm

Comment: @Curlas yes that's true the JSON structure is bit complex and I can't help in that as it is auto generated JSON from XSL file.  I regenerated the JSON to XSL and it's fine , I need to repeat the `__name ` from this JSON only and edit the `__text` value from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure is rather terrible, same objects keys with different data types makes things a little difficult. However this will return you a list of all `_name` fields.

You then bind that to your scope etc.

```
data
    .stylesheet['attribute-set']
    .map(x => {
        if (Array.isArray(x.attribute))
            return x.attribute.map(y => y['_name']);
        else
            return [x.attribute['_name']]; 
    })
    .reduce((accu, cur) => accu.concat(...cur), []);
```

It essentially extracts out the `_name` field into an array for each attribute set then reduces that into a single array.

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gncem6z1/)

Comment: And how  can I make changes on those key values and save it to same json again?

Comment: You could map the array. Depends on what you want. If you want to just manipulate the _name but keep the entire object then don't extract it out. Either way you've got a multidimensional array that you will find it easier to flatten.

Comment: @WhoAmI iv'e created a jsFiddle. If you're still having issues executing the code please create a fiddle that i can see it failing in.

Comment: @WhoAmI your exception in that fiddle is because `$scope` has not been defined. Once thats fixed youve got a dozen other exceptions because things don't exist, like `X2JS`. The code in the fiddle is not the code i have posted or similar? Have you coppied the wrong code?

Comment: Thanks , it is working fine now . I am now able to change the value in the array and need to remap it on my json object with the new value. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want all the values for `_name`. If you don't, please specify which values of `_name` you want. Firstly you'll have to restructure your data likes this with all the attributes in one array:

```
{
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute_set": [
      {
        "_name": "text-align",
        "__prefix": "xsl",
        "__text": "center"
      },
      {
        "_name": "__frontmatter",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "_name": "space-before",
        "__prefix": "xsl",
        "__text": "80mm"
      },
      {
        "_name": "space-before.conditionality",
        "__prefix": "xsl",
        "__text": "retain"
      },
      {
        "_name": "font-size",
        "__prefix": "xsl",
        "__text": "22pt"
      },
      {
        "_name": "font-weight",
        "__prefix": "xsl",
        "__text": "bold"
      },
      {
        "_name": "line-height",
        "__prefix": "xsl",
        "__text": "140%"
      },
      {
        "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      }
    ],
    "_xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
    "_xmlns:fo": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
}
```

And then running:

```
angular.forEach($scope.jsonObj.stylesheet.attribute_set, function(value, key) {
    console.log(value._name);
});
```

Comment: First of all I cannot restructure my JSON as it is a conversion output of a xslt file.  And yes I want to list all the `_name` key in my view and also accordingly edit my `_text` value and save it in the same JSON structure.